# Iterate with XMLDOM and vbs

Tags: xml, vbscript, xmldom

Can anyone give me a hint of how to get the values from G_Q9 if value in G_Q1 is equal to x?
If value G_Q1 <> x then continue to the next G_Q1.
I don't like the format of the XML file but I have to adapt to it.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generated by Oracle Reports version 12.2.1.3.0 -->
<WOKE611>
  <LIST_G_Q1>
    <G_Q1>
      <Value>1234</Value>
      <LIST_G_Q9>
        <G_Q9>
          <Value>0</Value>
        </G_Q9>
        <G_Q9>
          <Value>1</Value>
        </G_Q9>
      </LIST_G_Q9>
    </G_Q1>
   <G_Q1>
      <Value>5678</Value>
      <LIST_G_Q9>
        <G_Q9>
          <Value>0</Value>
        </G_Q9>
        <G_Q9>
          <Value>1</Value>
        </G_Q9>
      </LIST_G_Q9>
    </G_Q1>
  </LIST_G_Q1>
</WOKE611>
```

```vb
Dim i

Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0") 
objXMLDoc.Async = False 
objXMLDoc.Load("C:\temp\shortXml.xml")
Set NodeList = objXMLDoc.SelectNodes("//G_Q1/*")

For i = 1 To NodeList.Length 
    Set CurrNode = NodeList.NextNode
    If CurrNode.Text = "1234" Then
        WScript.Echo("How to continue to get the value of G_Q9/Value ?")
    End If
Next
```

---

I solved this by changing `SelectNodes("//G_Q1/*")` to `SelectNodes("//*")`.

Comment: @Lankymart Not really a duplicate, at least not of that question, since contrary to the *answer* the OP edited in, the actual *question* is not about traversing the entire XML structure.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers *"I solved this by changing SelectNodes("//G_Q1/*") to SelectNodes("//*")."*. Regardless, it's a question about traversal of the XMLDOM (entire or not) which has been covered over and over again.

Comment: Please re-read what I just wrote.

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly not possible that the supposed solution you added to your question would actually solve the problem you described (at least not without further modifications to your code), since it would iterate over *all* XML nodes instead of selecting just the values you want.

A proper solution to the problem would look somewhat like this:

```vb
xpath = "//G_Q1[Value='1234']/LIST_G_Q9/G_Q9/Value"
Set NodeList = objXMLDoc.SelectNodes(xpath)
For Each n In NodeList
    WScript.Echo n.Text
Next
```

Replace `WScript.Echo n.Text` with whatever other processing you need to perform.